# Break Text File into Multiple Pandas Dataframes using Headers from specific lines

Tags: pandas, dataframe, split, header

I have a single text file that looks like:

```
Filename and date
Header1   Header2   Header3
data      data      data
data      data      data
data      data      data

Filename2 and date2
Header1   Header2   Header3
data      data      data
data      data      data
```

..and so on for many blocks of data.

I am using `pd.read_csv` to open the file.

How do I split this into separate dataframes? The headers for each dataframe will be identical, but the "filename and date" need to be preserved for each one. Also, there is a different number of lines of data for each file.

Used 
`dfs = {
        k: pd.read_csv(pd.io.common.StringIO('\n'.join(dat)),delim_whitespace=True)
        for k, *dat in map(str.splitlines, open('my.csv').read().split('\n\n'))
    }`

but am getting

```
                  Header1 Header2 Header3
Filename and date   0    data    data    data
                    1    data    data    data
                    2    data    data    data
                   Filename2 and date2    
                   1    data    data    data
                   2    data    data    data
```

where "Filename2" "and" "date"2 are placed under the "Header1" "Header2" "Header3" columns like they are all part of 1 dataframe in 1 dict instead of making several different dataframes in the dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### dictionary comprehension

```
dfs = {
    k: pd.read_csv(pd.io.common.StringIO('\n'.join(dat)), delim_whitespace=True)
    for k, *dat in map(str.splitlines, open('my.csv').read().split('\n\n'))
}
```

Proof that it worked

```
pd.concat(dfs)

                      Header1 Header2 Header3
Filename and date   0    data    data    data
                    1    data    data    data
                    2    data    data    data
Filename2 and date2 0    data    data    data
                    1    data    data    data
```

Comment: I get     for k, *dat in map(str.splitlines, open(outfile).read().split('\n\n'))
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected at least 1, got 0). Is this because some of the columns have no data where other columns do?

Comment: ^^^needed to just add another '\n' on the split.

Comment: The only problem I see is that it puts all the data into a single dataframe under "filename and date" instead of a dict of multiple dataframes labeled by the different filename/date. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've shown one way to split it up.  You are only limited by your imagination.  Think of how you'd like to have it and I can help you get it there.  Usually, an OP (that's you) provides what they expect to see as the final result.

Comment: I want to see exactly how you placed it. I assumed that your result would put each data block into a dataframe which would all be placed into a dict. Using your help, the code only makes one dict with "filename and date" as the label and then puts all the data into a dataframe with "filename2 and date2" and so on placed as values under the "Header1" "Header2". I edited my question using your answer to show what the problem is vs what I am looking for.

Comment: I saw your edit.  I don't know how you're getting that unless your file isn't exactly as presented in your post.  I copied and pasted the code from your question and got the results I show.  The only difference is the file being parsed.

Comment: I realized it is because not all data in the rows has the same amount of spaces between each other. I made them the same in a sample file to test and it works as stated.